# Is there an official name for Lord Marshal's unique moves?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-riddick

In the movie, The Chronicles of Riddick, the leader of Necromonger, Lord Marshal, is seen executing a few uniques moves when fighting in melee.

He could move so fast that a shadow of his body would be left behind, he could throw punches so fast that shadows of his fists would stay behind, he could also take someone's soul away with his shadowy fists.

Is there an official name for his skills?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86124/visual-fuzziness-of-necromonger-actions-ships

Comment: Ah DNEG, I recall we were poking at Maya 1.0 in the studio and our Softimage guy went off to have a chat with some guys he knew. Came back a bit later saying the boys got together and started a little shop called Double Negative. Should've jumped ship...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is part of the Soulpower:

> ability to detach his soul from his body, granting him super speed, by means of his soul quickly moving to a different place and his body following it almost in an instant. This acts to give him speed in short bursts (or long term use for long distance travel), and allows him to go anywhere his soul can get to, regardless of whether his body (under normal conditions) could or not (e.g., on top a statue to the right of his throne). He's able to fly with this ability.
>
> He also has the ability to grab a person's soul out of their body, killing them, but he's unable to absorb the souls to become more powerful, but since the Soulpower recharges, he doesn't need to. This so called Soulpower he gained during his trip to the Underverse also grants him healing powers, which he can use to regenerate and to protect himself against harm.

Not sure of the script but the above comes from the only sites that spend anytime on it:

https://riddick.fandom.com/wiki/Lord_Marshal

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SoulPower

> The Lord Marshal of the Necromongers in The Chronicles of Riddick was transformed into a "Holy Half-Dead" because he visited and returned from the Underverse, the Necromongers' promised land. He shows particular mastery of souls, as he can move his own soul separate from his physical body, giving the illusion of Super-Speed. He can also directly take hold of anyone else's soul, with the victim dying as soon as he releases it.

Checked the script, Soulpower is not explicitly named, just lots of references to his 'soul':

> Now Lord Marshal spots the "officer" the one he saw rear of the hall -- and his soul flinches.

> And he knew. His half-dead soul sensed I was behind him.

> Closing on Lord Marshal. Just when we think
> we've caught him unaware, a "soul" head turns inside his
> physical head. His astral face stares at us for a moment
> before the physical face catches up.

> Lord Marshal approaches. Chillingly, a third arm -- red and
> ethereal -- separates from his body. This "astral" arm
> reaches inside the politico… fishes about for a moment…
> then violently rips something out and throws it on the floor
> for the everyone -- especially the gape-mouthed politico -- to see.

> It's a human soul. Red and ethereal. Silently screaming at
> the shock of being C-sectioned from the body of Politico #1.
> An empty husk, he falls and dies.

http://www.davidtwohy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CHRONICLES-OF-RIDDICK-2-June-2003_WaterMark.pdf

other links:

https://screenrant.com/riddick-prophecy-lord-marshal-necromonger-purifier/

> He might have been able to use the Soulpower to see Vaako sneaking up on him, but it didn't save him from the unexpected Furyan he didn't anticipate bringing him down.